# Why my google +1 button doesn't show statistics/numbers?

Tags: google-plus-one

I have more than 1K +1 for my website. And I want to show that number next to my +1 button as it shows in all other websites. But mine is not working.

If you are not understanding what i am trying to say then look at my website
http://come2chat.com

look at the top center of my webpage. It has a google +1 button but it doesn't show how many +1 I have on it.

to see the number of +1, i have to visit my google plus one profile at 
https://plus.google.com/107969039583165788589/posts

how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use another +1 button.
You can find the right ones here:

https://developers.google.com/+/web/+1button/#button-sizes

Looks like you need to change your data-annotation and data-size attributes.
The button generator at the top of the page I linked can help you find the look you want.

Comment: thanks I figured out why the count was not showing. I had annotation attribute set to none. Now i changed it to bubble. But now the count is just above my button which displaces my button from its true position. I want that count to show in left/right of my +1 button.

Comment: @ShubhamNishad You can fix that by setting data-size to "small", "medium" or removing it entirely.

Comment: @ShubhamNishad, if my answer helped you, please accept this as the best answer.